# Start from a given address in MIPS

Tags: mips, mips32, qtspim

How can i start from the address of static data 0x10008000 and move to 0x10008008?
I don't know if i am wrong but those addresses are for 3 registers,
and you can't store in the address 0x10008001.

Comment: Define _"start from"_ and _"move to"_. What exactly are you trying to do at 0x10008000? Load data? Store data? Execute code?

Comment: store data...more spicific change the LSB of this addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load those 3 words into `$t1 - $t3`:

```
lui $t0 0x1000
ori $t0 0x8000
lw $t1 0($t0)
lw $t2 4($t0)
lw $t3 8($t0)
```